# Unable to manage Mailjet via Azure

Tags: azure, mailjet

I know it sounds like a ticket meant for the Azure or Mailjet support directly but it's super hard to contact them on that topic.
Maybe someone has faced the same issue and could provide some guidance on how to workaround that.

Mailjet has recently announced that they would stop supporting Azure's integration. It basically means that Mailjet users who had a subscription through Azure need to dissociate their account.
The full procedure is described here: https://documentation.mailjet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043317814-Azure-migration-guide-

My problem is, **I can no longer manage the Mailjet resource on the Azure portal** as it keeps giving me errors when opening it (see the dump below).
It's a pretty generic error which seems to mean that the resource is no longer available while it should:

```json
{ "shellProps": { "sessionId": "...", "extName": "Microsoft_Azure_MarketplaceApps", "contentName": "AppServiceCommunicationPreferencesFormPart" }, "error": { "message": "Error loading your content", "error": 0, "code": null }}
```

I saw that **Mailjet is no longer available on Azure Markeplace**.
Do Marketplace resources break when they are retired from the store?

If someone ever encountered this specific error or if an experimented Azure user could see in it a more generic Azure error, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to get an answer from Mailjet's Technical, I couldn't wait any longer and simply decided to drop Mailjet in favor of another platform.

Given what Azure support told me, Marketplace apps are fully maintained by their publishers and the fact that the Mailjet management page stopped working was on Mailjet's fault. A shame to be sure, but that's a risk you must evaluate before going for 3rd parties on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

have the same experience .. have now moved the mailjet environment to their own environment.

have also been in contact with microsoft and it appears that it is often the case that when products are removed from the marketplace, they no longer function properly.

there is certainly a chance that this is causing the problem!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Theironrock95! How did you manage to move to a "full" Mailjet environment? Did you just create a new account or could you find a way to follow the procedure described on the article I shared?

Comment: I created a new account!

Comment: I thought about creating a new one as well. I've managed to contact Mailjet support on that topic and will see if we can workaround Azure to do that. I'll let my final response as the solution to this thread.

Comment: okey after that please close the topic by hitting aswer under vote